# Unsynchronized builds between teams

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment

We're working on an app where we share the UI developments with another team while "hiding" the server code from them. They'd get daily builds and deploy their server with these jars.
What's happening is:

1. Early in the morning, there is a build
2. Update their jars
3. They get the jars and deploy their to start their server

What would happen (and shouldn't) is that the build fails in the morning and they don't get their update. We'll have to fix it, rebuild everything and update them which can get frustrating for both teams.

Even if this didn't happen, it's still a drag to wait until the next day to get all modifications.

My question is : is there any possibility to update them constantly without having to install the servers locally on their machines and let them get svn updates?

**Note:** I'm not the one handeling deployement so I might have missed some points.

Comment: I would suggest you run a Maven repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory to host all built jars. That way the other team can always consume the latest so called "snapshot" build of the code under construction. This would be a common workflow for collaborating teams.

Comment: Actually, we're already using nexus to "update their jars". Problem is they're still dependent on the build for the server side. Which mean at each commit UI + Server related we need to rebuild and update them.

Comment: If you're using Jenkins then each code commit should automatically trigger a rebuild of the affected module. The dependency update trigger can be used to automatically build other modules that might depend on this snapshot https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Dependency+Update+trigger In conclusion, with Jenkins + Nexus managing your builds and jars, I'm confused as to why teams have to wait 24 hours to sync up.

Comment: I've looked more into it and the reason why builds aren't automatic when commiting is that it's a monolithic app (which we're moving out from it slowly) and though it takes a long time to compile/build. It's a multitude of problems that make the process so rigid. We shall fix it one step at a time. Thanks for the insight